# Split Text in .TextRange

Tags: vba, powerpoint

[image]

My objective is to split the List. Currently, I'm using `Shapes().TextFrame.TextRange` to read the text within the shape. We can use `Mid()` to split characters; however, I was wondering how I could go about splitting these lines instead as the characters in each line vary.

I'd like to only show the 2nd line (say) in the MsgBox. How do I proceed?

Thank you!

Comment: Typically you'd use `Split(yourText, vbLf)` but you've not explained exactly what your trying to achieve here - split *into what* ?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity, I'd like to only show the 2nd line in the MsgBox. How would I proceed after splitting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let PPT do the heavy lifting for you:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    With .TextFrame.TextRange
        MsgBox .Paragraphs(2)
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can be solved without any split when within text box?

```
 Sub test1()

Dim resultString As String

resultString = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange

MsgBox resultString

End Sub
```

And the outcome:

[image]

You will only need to split the text when it is within main title box in ppt, take note on the special character that unable to show in the code below:

```
Sub test1()

Dim resultString As String
Dim sArray
Dim i As Long

sArray = Split(ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange, "")

resultString = ""
For i = LBound(sArray) To UBound(sArray)
    If resultString <> "" Then
        resultString = resultString & vbNewLine & sArray(i)
    Else
        resultString = sArray(i)
    End If
Next

MsgBox resultString

End Sub
```

Code with special character

[image]

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The command to split text into pieces is `Split`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

```
Dim t As String, tokens() As String, i As Long
t = "ABC,DEF,,XYZ"
tokens = Split(t, ",")
For i = LBound(tokens) To UBound(tokens)
    Debug.Print i, tokens(i)
Next
```

Would give you an array with 4 elements in variable `tokens`. This is always 0-indexed:

```
 0            ABC
 1            DEF
 2            
 3            XYZ
```

Now all you need to know is the character that defines the line break. If you created the shape in Powerpoint, that's the Carriage Return character, in VBA there is a constant `vbCr` for that:

```
 Dim sh As Shape
 set sh = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1) 
 t = sh.TextFrame.TextRange
 tokens = Split(t, vbCr)
```

It works the same in **Word**, however in **Excel** it seems you need to use `TextFrame2` and the separator is the Line Feed character:

```
 t = sh.TextFrame2.TextRange
 tokens = Split(t, vbLf)
```